# How to count until a number with timer peripheral

Tags: timer, stm32f4, hal-library

I'm trying to use the TIM peripheral to count external pulses until a number and throw a interruption. I'm using STM32F429 and HAL library. I am initializing the TIM2 with this code:

```
void InitializeTimer2()
{

    TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig;
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;


    htim2.Instance = TIM2;
    htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
    htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim2.Init.Period = 5;
    htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    if(HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        /* Initialization Error */
        Error_Mensage("TIM2");
    }


    sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_EXTERNAL1;
    sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_TI1FP1;
    sSlaveConfig.TriggerPolarity = TIM_TRIGGERPOLARITY_RISING;
    sSlaveConfig.TriggerFilter = 15;
    HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sSlaveConfig);

    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig);

    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);
}
```

But I tried many HAL_TIM functions to get the interruption but with no success.

It will be a pleasure to provide any other helpful code...

Comment: Have you tried setting an Output Compare register to the desired count?

Comment: No, I thought that it would be possible to get something like a interruption informing an overflow.

Comment: Count down from your required value until the counter overflows?

Comment: Yeah I tried it before...do you know if is there this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

the answer is to use the function `HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback`:

```
/* TIM5 init function */
void MX_TIM5_Init(void)
{

    TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig;
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

    htim5.Instance = TIM5;
    htim5.Init.Prescaler = 0;
    htim5.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim5.Init.Period = 10;
    htim5.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim5);

    sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_EXTERNAL1;
    sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_TI1FP1;
    sSlaveConfig.TriggerPolarity = TIM_TRIGGERPOLARITY_RISING;
    sSlaveConfig.TriggerFilter = 15;
    HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim5, &sSlaveConfig);

    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim5, &sMasterConfig);
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim->Instance == TIM5)
    {
        count2++;
    }
}
```

I initialized the timer with this: `HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim5)`.

This code permits to count external pulses and throw an interruption every 10 pulses.

Reggards!!